# Laravel know variable inside function, but does not know in return

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel excel to export my data. Inside map function, the $credit and $debit variables but when returning them, it throws a error.

The error is :

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

here is my map function:

```
public function map($partner): array
{
    $credit = Bank::whereId($partner->credit)->first(); // also used: Bank::find($partner->credit);
    $debit = Bank::whereId($partner->debit)->first();
    dd($credit->name) // returns 'test'

    return [
        $partner->full_name, // this returns correctly.
        $credit->name, // returns "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"
                       // if use $credit, it returns whole credit object.
        $debit->name,  // returns "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"
                       // if use $credit, it returns whole debit object.
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like few `$partner` has no `credit` or `debit` so check null condition

```
public function map($partner): array
{
    $credit = Bank::whereId($partner->credit)->first(); Bank::find($partner->credit);
    $debit = Bank::whereId($partner->debit)->first();
   

    return [
        $partner->full_name, 
        $credit->name??null,
        $debit->name??null,          
    ];
}
```

Also you can  do

```
$data=[$partner->full_name];
isset($credit->name)? array_push($data,$credit->name)?null;
isset($debit->name)? array_push($data,$debit->name)?null;
  
return $data;
```

Comment: Thanks John Lobo, The issue is that: $credit->name isn't null, It does exists. it does exists inside the function and I dumped it. but it does not return it

Comment: @MahdiJafari have you checked for all records ? since  dd($credit->name)  will check for only one record

Comment: Not yet. Let me check it